# How to (not) rerun c++ code?

Tags: c++

I am doing the basic console c++ "do u want to rerun program?" dance,
and failing. This is what I'm using

```
int main()
{
  char repeat = 'y';        
  while (rep == 'y' || 'Y')
  {

   {
   //primary code is here
   }

  cout << "\n\tRerun program? y/n";
  cin >> repeat;
  if (rep == 'n' || 'N')
  {cout << "\n\tExiting program\n";}
  }

return 0;
}
```

When my program finishes, it restarts and outputs "Exiting program"
 no matter what I input at "Rerun program?"I understand this has
something to do with flushing or resetting the char "repeat"?
No idea how to do that and google isn't helping.

I can submit the primary program code on request, but I doubt it has
 anything to do with this error.

Comment: `while (rep == 'y' || rep == 'Y')` and `if (rep == 'n' || rep == 'N')
 ` is what you're looking for presumably.

Comment: Alternatively, use a `break` command after you print "Exiting".

Comment: Wow, I need to sleep. Thanks! post it as answer and I'll approve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (rep == 'n' || 'N')` will be always true,
because it actually doing `if( (rep =='n') or 'N')` (`'N'` has nonzero value which mean the if-statement is doing : `if( (rep =='n') or true)` ), so you always got "Exiting program" printed.

you should you `if (rep == 'n' || rep =='N')`

and the same, your while statement should be while `(rep == 'y' || rep == 'Y')`

OR

move the

```
cout << "\n\tExiting program\n";
```

out your while loop without condition to get it printed only when finish the loop